# [PlayFramework 2.5][Intellij] Play-enhancer problems

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework

`sbt-play-enhancer` is not generating getters and setters for random classes.
What can I do expect adding getters and setters everywhere?

I'm using:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.1.0")
```

I already tried `activator-clean` but without any success. And, because of that, sometimes binding fails. Sometimes, even it won't save changes.

Answer (score 0):

The enhancer looks for all fields on Java classes that:

1. are public
2. are non static
3. are non final

[link to docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/PlayEnhancer#Operation)

ps: if it doesnt help, try to delete target folders